# Access List of List

Tags: c#, list

I created a List of List to store randomly generated data however my implementations shows the following intellisense error "The variable name doesn't exist in current context". Where have I gone wrong? Here are the required portions of my code.

```
           List<List<string>> DataList = new List<List<string>>();
           //Some Code
            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
            {
                List<string> strVal = new List<string>();
                foreach (string someVal in SomeList)
                {                    
                    //Some Code
                    strVal.Add(data);
                }

                DataList.Add(strVal);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
            {
                foreach (IList<string> name in DataList)
                {
                    foreach (string listVal in strVal) // Error Here
                    {
                        //Some Code
                    }                    
                }
            }
```

Where have I gone wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  foreach (IList<string> name in DataList)
            {
                foreach (string listVal in strVal) // Error Here
                {
                    //So
```

should be

```
  foreach (IList<string> name in DataList)
            {
                foreach (string listVal in name ) // Error Here
                {
                    //So
```

Answer (score 2):

You are defining `strVal` **inside** the first `for` loop and trying to access it in the second one.

`strVal` goes out of scope at the end of the first `for` loop. Define it outside the first loop in order for it to be accessible by both loops.

```
List<List<string>> DataList = new List<List<string>>();
//Some Code
List<string> strVal = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{        
    foreach (string someVal in SomeList)
    {                    
        //Some Code
        strVal.Add(data);
    }
    DataList.Add(strVal);
}
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    foreach (IList<string> name in DataList)
    {
       foreach (string listVal in strVal)
       {
            //Some Code
       }                    
    }
}
```

This is what is causing your error, though it might not be what you intended to do. See @Chen 's answer for something more logical :)