# How to access unique sublist from another class

Tags: c#, string, list, sublist

I have a list of list and I want to access for example the second sublist and add a string.

```
 public static List<List<string>> logsIP1 = new List<List<string>>();

 public static void logsList()
 {
        logsIP1.Add(new List<string> { });
        logsIP1.Add(new List<string> { });
        logsIP1.Add(new List<string> { });
 }
```

I want something like

```
Logs.logsIP1.Add(List<string>[0]("test");
```

Comment: Edit your question to add the programming language tag.

Comment: To get the n item use yourList.Item[n].Add("new string");

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Add string? Please, be more specific and provide more details.

Comment: I want acces for expemple to second list and add strings from another class, to second sublist

Comment: logsIP1.Item[1].Add("your string");

Comment: https://ctrlv.cz/2l2L I can't

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14111928/access-list-of-list

Comment: Thanks you, I try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
 public static List<List<string>> logsIP1 = new List<List<string>>();
 public static void Add(int index, string value)
 {
    var nestedList = logsIP1[index];
    nestedList.Add(value);
  }
```

Then you can use method `Add()` to insert new value into nested list by index of main list

Comment: Thanks but, I want add string to sublist from another class

Comment: @TomášFišer and What is the problem? Why did not you describe in question about another class?

Comment: Sorry about that, I just want add strings to second sublist for expamle

Comment: @TomášFišer Ok, no problem but how can I help you without informations?. So, you want to add string to nested list from other class?

Comment: yes, just want this, if I do something add string to second sublist, then I do something other and add string to thirth list etc.

Comment: @TomášFišer Please check my updated answer if it is fit to you.

Comment: @TomášFišer Really? Glad to have been of help

Answer (score 0):

> I want access, for example, the second list and add strings from another class

Break this into two parts.  First, you need to access the second item in your outer list.  To access an item at an index, you'd use:

```
List<string> second = logsIP1[1];
```

Now you have a reference to the second list and can add items to it:

```
second.Add("one");
second.Add("two");
```